# Range of Influence of the Wave Equation?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Suppose $u$ is a solution of the two-dimensional wave equation
$$u_{tt}-c^2 \Delta u=f(x)$$ 
with initial values $u(0),u_t(0)$ that have support on the disc $x_1^2+x_2^2 \le 1$. Up to what time can you be sure that $u=0$ at the point $(x_1,x_2)=(2,3)$?

**My attempt:**

I think it depends on the point farthest from $(2,3)$ in the disc, which is $(-\frac{-2 \sqrt {13}}{13},-\frac{-3 \sqrt {13}}{13})$. Then by the range of influence of wave equation, the time should be $t=\frac{14+2\sqrt {13}}{c}$, where $c$ is constant of two dimensional wave equation $u_{tt}-c^2 \Delta u=f(x)$, $14+2\sqrt {13}$ is the distance of $(2,3)$ and $(-\frac{-2 \sqrt {13}}{13},-\frac{-3 \sqrt {13}}{13})$.

Is that right? Can anyone help? Thanks so much!:)

Comment: I'd rather think nearest, not farthest. The disturbance from nearest point will come earliest to the test point.

Comment: @Ruslan I am still confused. I also think that the farthest point will need more time to disturb the point $(2,3)$. So does that mean we cannot be sure $u=0$ at $(2,3)$ until that time? So I think it is the farthest point.

Comment: You can be sure that $u=0$ at test point until this point gets hit by the first disturbance which gets there. Of course, the first disturbance which gets there is the one from the nearest nonzero point.

Answer (score 1):

The initial values at the point on the unit circle closest to $(2,3)$ are the ones that first influence the function value at this point.

Due to [Evans Book](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=GSM-19-R), Chapter 2.4.3, Theorem 6, we know that if $u$ is a solution to the wave equation (with speed $c$ normed to 1 for the moment) and $u(0)\equiv u_t(0)\equiv 0$ on the ball $B(x_0,t_0)$, then $u\equiv 0$ within the cone 
$$C=\{(x,t)\,|\,0\leq t\leq t_0,|x-x_0|\leq t_0-t\}.$$
This easily extends to the case of constant speed $c$ different to $1$ by simply scaling, so our condition is $u(0)\equiv u_t(0)\equiv 0$ within $B(x_0,ct_0)$.

What's therefore left to do is to compute $\operatorname{dist}(x_0,B(0,1))$, with $x_0=(2,3)$:
Since you suppose that the support of $u(0),u_t(0)$ is within the unit disc $B(0,1)$, the searched-for $t_0$ is given by $t_0=\operatorname{dist}(x_0,B(0,1))/c$.

But this distance is just the Euclidean norm minus the radius of the unit circle, that is
$$||x_0||=\sqrt{2^2+3^2}-1=\sqrt{13}-1.$$ This finally leads to $$t_0=\frac{\sqrt{13}-1}{c}.$$

**Remark:** With your approach, you were on the way to answer a different question, that is: How long do I have to wait while measuring at $x_0$ until I can be sure that my initial data $u(0),u_t(0)$ vanish. You have however a sign error for the farthest point, which is in fact $$x_\text{far}=\left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}},-\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}}\right).$$ I can't follow at all the second calculation, but the time (I call it $t_1$) should be 
$$t_1=\frac{\sqrt{13}+1}{c},$$ 
since the distance to $t_1$ is exactly $2$ larger than the distance to $t_0$.

I sketched the situation in [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427es8l3lng8dt).[image]