# Finite Speed of Propagation for $u_{tt} - \Delta u + qu = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, wave-equation, hyperbolic-equations

I am looking to show that there is some type of finite speed of propagation property for PDEs of the form

$$
    u_{tt} -\Delta u + q u = 0
$$
Where we can assume that $q$ is as smooth or integrable as we like.

We know that for the standard wave equation $$w_{tt} - \Delta w = 0$$
that if $w(x,0) = w_t(x,0) = 0$ for all $x\in B(x_0,r)$, then $w = 0$ on the cone
$$ 
     K = \{ (x,t)\in \mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}:0\leq t\leq r, |x-x_0|\leq r-t \} 
$$
This result is shown on Page 84 of Evans *Partial Differential Equations*. It was show at ([Prove domain of Dependence Inequality for the Wave Equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040729/prove-domain-of-dependence-inequality-for-the-wave-equation)) that the local energy estimate holds if the potential term $q$ is positive. It is often mentioned hyperbolic PDEs have finite speed of propagation, but I can't find a source that proves the claim in the general case.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand. What is the actual question?

Comment: @MatthewCassell We have this finite speed of propagation property for the standard wave equation and I would like to know if anyone has a reference or explanation for why the result would hold for a general symmetric hyperbolic PDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are proofs of more general problems (see last paragraph of this answer), but for now let's talk about the equation :
$$
u_{tt}-\Delta u = q(x)u \quad (t,x) \in [0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^n \tag{1} \label{1}
$$
in which $q:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. (this $q$ is $-q$ of your problem but since there's no assumption on sign of $Im(q)$ it doesn't matter, it's just easier for notations in my proof) 
As you said the cone (backward in time) at $(t_0,x_0)$ can be defined as :
$$
C(t_0,x_0) :=\{ (t,x)\in [0,T] \times \mathbb{R}^n, 0 \leq t\leq t_0, |x-x_0|\leq t_0-t \}
$$
also at every section of time $t \in [0,t_0]$ we define
$$
B(x_0,t) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n , |x-x_0|\leq t\}.
$$
with these notations; the statement of theorem becomes:

> *Theorem* (finite speed of propagation) : 
>  Let $u$ be a  $C^2$ solution of $\eqref{1}$ in $C(t_0,x_0)$. if $u=u_t=0$ on $B(x_0,t_0)$,
> then $u=0$ in $C(t_0,x_0)$.

Note that $B(x_0,t_0)$ is section of $C(t_0,x_0)$ in $t=0$.
**Proof:** 
define
$$
e(t):= \int_{B(x_0,t_0-t)} (u^2+|\partial u|^2)dx
$$
where $|\partial u|^2 = |u_t|^2+|\nabla u|^2.$ By rewriting $e(t)$ integral in polar coordinate, we have:
$$
e(t) = \int_0^{t_0-t}\int_{\partial B(x_0,s)} (u^2+|\partial u|^2)d\sigma ds .
$$
then we have:
$$
\dot{e}(t) := \frac{d}{dt} e(t) = \int_{B(x_0,t_0-t)} 2(u u_t + u_t u_{tt} + \underbrace{ \nabla u . \nabla u_t}_{I_1} ) dx - \int_{\partial B(x_0,s)} (u^2+|\partial u|^2)d\sigma . \tag{2} \label{2}
$$
we know that :
$$
div(u_t \nabla u) = \nabla u . \nabla u_t + u_t \Delta u
$$
so we can rewrite $I_1$ in $\eqref{2}$ to get the form of $\eqref{1}$ and use the divergence theorem. continuing from $\eqref{2}$:
$$
\dot{e}(t) = 2\int_{B(x_0,t_0-t)} u_t (u + u_{tt} - \Delta u) dx + 2 \int_{B(x_0,t_0-t)} div(u_t \nabla u) dx-  \int_{\partial B(x_0,s)} (u^2+|\partial u|^2)d\sigma  \\
= 2\int_{B(x_0,t_0-t)} u_t (u + u_{tt} - \Delta u) dx + 2 \int_{\partial B(x_0,s)} u_t \nabla u . \nu d \sigma -  \int_{\partial B(x_0,s)} (u^2+|\partial u|^2)d\sigma 
$$
where $\nu$ is outward unit normal of $\partial B(x_0,s)$. we can bound this integral by
$$
2 |u_t \nabla u . \nu| \leq 2 |u_t| |\nabla u| \leq |u_t|^2 + |\nabla u|^2 = |\partial u|^2 .
$$
so we have
$$
\dot{e}(t) = 2\int_{B(x_0,t_0-t)} u_t (u + u_{tt} - \Delta u) dx + \int_{\partial B(x_0,s)} \underbrace{\big( (2 u_t \nabla u . \nu - |\partial u|^2) - u^2 \big)}_{\leq 0} d\sigma
$$
hence :
$$
\dot{e}(t) \leq  2\int_{B(x_0,t_0-t)} u_t (u + \underbrace {u_{tt} - \Delta u}_{qu}) dx = 2\int_{B(x_0,t_0-t)} u_t (1+q(x))u \, dx. \tag{3}\label{3}
$$
Let's define $F(r,p):= (1+q(r))p$ . since $F(x,0)=0$ we have
$$
(1+q)u-0 = F(x,u)-F(x,0) = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial s} F(x,su)ds \\
= \int_0^1 \big( \frac{\partial}{\partial p} F(x,su) \big) \, u \, ds \leq |u| \int_0^1 | \frac{\partial}{\partial p} F(x,su)| ds .
$$
therefore
$$
|F(x,u)| \leq C |u|
$$
where
$$
C := \max_{(t,x) \in C(t_0,x_0)} \int_0^1 | \frac{\partial}{\partial p} F(x,s\, u(t,x))| ds. \tag{4} \label{4}
$$
Using this inequality in $\eqref{3}$ we get:
$$
\dot{e}(t) \leq 2\int_{B(x_0,t_0-t)} u_t F(x,u) \, dx \leq 2C \int_{B(x_0,t_0-t)} |u_t| |u| dx \\
\leq C \int_{B(x_0,t_0-t)} (|u|^2+|u_t|^2) dx \leq C  \int_{B(x_0,t_0-t)} (|u|^2+|\partial u|^2) dx = C e(t).
$$
$\forall t \in [0,t_0]$ we have $\dot{e}(t) \leq  C e(t)$ and also by assumption of theorem $e(0)=0$. using [Gronwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) we deduce that $e(t)=0$ for $t \in [0,t_0]$ therefore $u=0$ in $C(t_0,x_0)$ .$\square$ 
 
it's worth mentioning that if you look at this proof you can see it's valid for more general form of $F(r,p)$! even form of $F(x,t,u,\partial u,\partial^2 u)$ with some assumptions! so if you look at $\eqref{4}$ you can be more precise when $F(r,p)=(1+q(r))p$ but for abovementioned reason, I didn't simplify it more.

Comment: Perfect! Wonderfully explained! Thank you