# Problem about the disturbance of wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

What is meant by "disturbance" of a wave equation?

"Consider a vibrating infinite string whose displacement is given by the wave equation $$U_{tt}=U_{xx},$$ means (c=1). Suppose at $t=0$, the string is subjected to a disturbance exactly in the intervals $[1,2]$ and $[4,5]$. At $t=10$, describe the positions on the string which will be affected by the initial disturbance."

Comment: Please consider formatting your formulas using Latex notation with dollar signs.

Comment: is my answer what you've been looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "disturbance" one usually means a sudden energy input, here in terms of initial values that "disturb" the before non-vibrating string.

Since wave signals (distubrances, singularities) propagate with finite speed (see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040609/range-of-influence-of-the-wave-equation/1533305#1533305) and the references therein, it will need some time until the disturbance can influence the solution $U$ at a certain point.

Hint 1 to your (homework?) question: You are asked to find the domain of influence of the initial signal at a time $t=10$, which will be a bounded interval. Hint 2: The disturbances are propagating with the wave speed (in your case, $c=1$).